# How can I set up a keybind to restrict mouse movement between two monitors?

Tags: multiple-monitors, monitor-settings

I have recently began using two monitors and appreciating the convenience. However, I dislike the behaviour of moving the mouse between monitors.

For context, my second monitor is abour a foot lower than my first monitor, as there is not room for both to be actually beside on another. So, if I have them aligned perfectly aside eachother in settings, so that the mouse moves seamlessly from the left edge of monitor 1 to the right edge of monitor 2, I find my mouse also gets *lost* more easily. Perhaps it is a small thing, but it genuinely bothers me quite a bit, especially when I want to turn off the PC and it ends up on monitor 2 and not in the bottom-left corner of the screen. (I acknowledge that I could alt+F4 to shutdown, or Windows key to pop-up the menu, and I have. They are less intuitive solutions to me, though.)

If I have them joined more realistically, where monitor 2 is connected only by its top-half of the right end of its screen, then when I drag things from one screen to another, they get "caught" easily on Windows' fullscreen function of dragging something to the edge of a screen to maximize it.

I am wondering if there is a way I can set it up so that my mouse *never* moves between these two monitors, *unless...* X occurs, whatever that conditional solution may be. My first thought was a keybind, such as holding down a function button which "takes down the barrier" thereby allowing the mouse to move between monitors and behave as expected without a barricade.

Comment: a few more paragraphs would add some helpful structure to the text. otherwise an interesting question

Comment: A workaround is to go to the mouse settings (the old, control panel style one), and enable pressing ctrl to locate the mouse pointer